# Using Docker pipeline inside a containerized Jenkins on Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to run Jenkins inside of Docker and use the Jenkins Docker Pipeline.  I'm using 17.12.0-ce-mac45 (21669) which is the edge edition of Docker.  I follow the tutorial on Jenkins's website and run:

```
docker run \
  --rm \
  -u root \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v "$HOME":/home \
 jenkinsci/blueocean
```

Everything starts up ok but when I try to run just a simple pipeline such as

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:7-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying

```
sh: can't create /var/jenkins_home/workspace@tmp/durable-070664e3/jenkins-log.txt: nonexistent directory
sh: can't create /var/jenkins_home/workspace@tmp/durable-070664e3/jenkins-result.txt: nonexistent directory
```

Something else comes up before that which says:
    `Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container`

Anyone else run into this problem?  When I use docker-machine, it works but just not on Docker for Mac edge.  I'm not sure if it works on Docker for Mac stable.  My only guess it that the error that comes up saying that Jenkins doesn't seem to think it's in a container is the root of the problem.  I did notice in the Github repository on [this line](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/b237e3266eb01b26f4a7b1a69856b0198774a2bb/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/client/DockerClient.java#L85) that it expects it to look like "/docker/" and that's what makes Jenkins think it's in a container or not.  In docker-machine, it looks exactly like that, but on Docker for Mac Edge, it looks like `/docker-ce/docker/`

Comment: Does just a freestyle job in jenkins works with `docker ps`?

Comment: I would try to leave   `-v "$HOME":/home` \ and just use `docker volume create jenkins-data` before the docker run. I was able to get it work, but I was using a different image: getintodevops/jenkins-withdocker:lts

Comment: Yeah. The command has to take place inside the Docker image in order for it to fail. Running docker ps is fine. I tried removing the $home and it didn’t do anything. Jenkins didn’t really explain why it was needed so that was the first thing I removed

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue with `Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6` on macOS, somebody has already reported it as a bug in the docker-workflow-plugin https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49005, for now I'm using docker-machine as a workaround until there is an update to the docker-workflow-plugin or Docker change the cgroup naming.